# Как выводить в поиске все записи?

Tags: php, wordpress

В настройках wordpress указано выводить только одну статью на одну страницу. Но вот при поиске по сайту это неудобно, хочется видеть сразу все записи. Как для страницы поиска сделать исключение, чтобы на ней выводились сразу все совпадения, а не по-одному?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш `functions.php`:

```php
function custom_searchpage_query( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_searchpage_query' );
```